# Full path as a bean property in Spring

Tags: java, spring

Say, I have the following bean in Spring context:

```
<bean class="some.class.BlabBlahBlah">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:somefile.xml"/>
</bean>
```

Currently `somefile.xml` is placed in the `src/main/java`, but I'd like to place it somewhere in the file system. Is there a way to do that? I tried to set full path instead of this `classpath:` but it didn't work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By [reference (Table 4.1)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/resources.html#resources-implementations), you should probably use a file system resource path:

```
<property name="location" value="file:/path/to/file.xml" />
```

Comment: How to give path for windows?